# Team Foundation Server: Creating UI components as part of code check-in

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008, tfs

Our organisation is using Team Foundation Server. At the moment, developers are manually adding issue tracking references to their check-in comments. We have a custom check-in policy that enforces a valid reference has been added to the comments.

What I'd like to be able to do is provide the user with a user friendly dialog/UI component that allows them to select an issue from a list which will then insert the reference, in the required format, into the comment box.

We are mainly using Visual Studio 2010 but some development still happens on Visual Studio 2008. The issue tracking software is a 3rd party one called OnTime.

Is this possible? Can someone help point me in the right direction.

Comment: Why aren't you using the standard way of associating a checkin with a work item?  Even the original tfs 2005 shows a list of work items to associate checkins with.

Comment: Really. Just use an "Active Issues Assigned to Me" query

Comment: What are you using for issue tracking?

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that were using a separate product for issue tracking (OnTime).

Comment: Thought about extending your already in place custom check-in policy with a friendly dialog, showing the available OnTime issues and programmatically changing the comment to include the issue reference?

Comment: Extending the in place custom check-in policy with a user friendly dialog would be perfect but I'm not sure how to do that hence the original question. Please let me know if there are any good resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doh! It was as simple as creating an instance of a form and calling ShowDialog within the Evaluate method.